# EME Conformance Tests - WidevineH264MultiMediaKeySession

Tags: cobalt, widevine, multikey

For [2018]EME Conformance Tests - v20171221
WidevineH264MultiMediaKeySession

I find this test for 8 times Initialize & 8 times GenerateKeyRequest for Key
So I can get 8 times provisioning message for key license.

But the Test's success situation is as follows:

In emeTest-20171221164539.js

> runner.checkGE(video.currentTime, 15, 'currentTime');
>   runner.checkEq(testEmeHandler.keySessions.length, 8,
>   'keySessionCount'); runner.checkEq(testEmeHandler.keyCount, 128,
>   'keyCount');

Current Time great than 15 sec is pass.
Session count is 8 is the same.
But Keycount=128, I can't pass it. Only 8 time generateRequest.
I can't get 128 keys for 16 keys in one session for this test.

and I find in emeManager-20171221164539.js
    onKeyStatusesChange() { self.keyCount++; }

So I assume I need to get 128 AddKey() for onKeyStatusesChange()
But Now I have no idea to solve it.

I am using Cobalt RC 11.119147. and Widevine CDM 3.2.1

1. Is this version RC11 is support for multiKeyseeion >
2. Is there any Sample to process this Test for Widevine  CDM process ?
3. Why need 8 times Init with 8 times GenerateRequest ?
   why not one init and 8 times GenerateRequest ?
   does Init need to clean Something ? or We need 8 CDM instance ? Each one have only one session ?

Comment: Is any one can help to explain OnSessionKeyStatusesChangedFunc(
  SbDrmSystem wrapped_drm_system, void* context, const void* session_id, int session_id_size, int number_of_keys, const SbDrmKeyId* key_ids, const SbDrmKeyStatus* key_statuses); What is  int number_of_keys, const SbDrmKeyId* key_ids, const SbDrmKeyStatus* key_statuses  ????? How to call back with these three param.

Answer (score 0):

We recently fixed a bug in the test, is it possible for you to try again to see if you can still reproduce the above mentioned issue.

Comment: Could you explain for OnSessionKeyStatusesChangedFunc( SbDrmSystem wrapped_drm_system, void* context, const void* session_id, int session_id_size, int number_of_keys, const SbDrmKeyId* key_ids, const SbDrmKeyStatus* key_statuses); What is int number_of_keys, const SbDrmKeyId* key_ids, const SbDrmKeyStatus* key_statuses ????? How to call back with these three param.

Comment: There can be multiple keys in one session.  |number_of_keys| is the number of the keys in the session, it also indicates how many elements are in the next two arrays.  |keys_ids| and |key_statuses| contain the key ids and statuses of these keys respectively.

Comment: Ｄo you have any smaple code to call OnSessionKeyStatusesChangedFunc() with those parameter ?

Comment: I find how to implement those parameter. thanks for your answer